# How to know the amount of data should be fed to "wide and deep learning" model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a beginner in deep learning, following the code from [tensorflow wide_n_deep_learning_tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py), I want to design my own prediction model with my own data. The data is very big, more than 1 million examples, and I have to determine how much data should be fed to model for training. As I known, the old approach is plotting the curve (relationship between data and score) like this [image]

Focused on wide and deep learning sample code, is there any way to plot that curve in tensorboard or is there any another approach to find out the relationship between the amount of data and the accuracy of model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Tensorflow summaries which are essentially logs. And in order to write logs you need a log writer (or what it is called in tensorflow) a SummaryWriter. So you should add the following line before your train loop.

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

This will create a log folder and save the graph structure. After your training you can start tensorboard and it will show you all the graphs.

```
tensorboard --logdir=<your-path-to-the-log-dir> --port 6006
```

EDIT: To log dynamic values you will have to add some more instructions like these

```
tf.scalar_summary("cost", cross_entropy)
tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)
```

For a short and easy tutorial go [here](http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/04/how-to-use-tensorboard/) (deprecated)

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) you can find the official tutorial about Tensorboard based on the MNIST example

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, the solution is deprecated and the sample code also logs all curves in a folder but it is for one fit size dataset and I don't know how to determine the amount of data is enough

Comment: If your data is to big, then you should test your model on a stratified sample of about 10% of the data. You could also use Keras as an Highlevel API for Tensorflow, which has an easy callback to Tensorboard. Just for testing if you want to stay on pure Tensorflow later.